# Write kafka topic data to redis using docker

Tags: docker, redis, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using [this repository](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-redis) kafka connect to redis.

**Explain:** What I want to do is to write kafka topics data into redis using docker.  They have created a readme file to instruct how to set the configuration of the kafka:

```
curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data @connector.json http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

`connector.json` file contains:

```
{
  "config" : {
    "name" : "RedisSinkConnector1",
    "connector.class" : "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max" : "1",
    "topics" : "mostafa"
  }
}
```

**Problem:** I know how to create a new topic in kafka, but the problem is where I don't know how to change the docker-compose or test the connection. While I have created a new topic in kafka, nothing shown in redis database!

I would be thankful if anyone could help me.

Comment: @mchawre There isn't any problem in log files and the containers work perfectly.

Comment: Well, you at least need to give `redis.hosts` to point at the Docker container for Redis. The default of localhost won't work. Also, please look at the /status Kafka Connect endpoint

Comment: @cricket_007 Would you please explain more and give me more clues?

Comment: Add another json key "redis.hosts"... Point it at the Docker service name for your redis container. And http://localhost:8083/connectors/RedisSinkConnector1/status

Comment: @cricket_007 would you please say it as an answer to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following configuration would resolve the problem.

```
{
  "name" : "RedisSinkConnector1",
  "config" : {
    "connector.class" : "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max" : "1",
    "topics" : "mostafa",
    "redis.hosts": "redis:6379",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
  }
}
```

add kafka-connect in docker-compose file

```
kafka-connect:
    hostname: kafka-connect
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest
    container_name: kafka-connect
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    depends_on:
      - schema-registry
      **- redis**
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "quickstart-avro"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: "quickstart-avro-config"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: "quickstart-avro-offsets"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: "quickstart-avro-status"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      **CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-connect"**
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/jars:/etc/kafka-connect/jars
```

**depends_on redis and CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME variable very important in resolving this issue**

Comment: Good job Mehradad!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, there is no Kafka Connect container in the compose file there, so you'll need to add one, or start Kafka Connect outside of Docker on your host machine.

Then, it's not clear if you've gotten the Redis connector properly loaded, so open up http://localhost:8083/connector-plugins to see if it is (this will also verify you've started the Connect Server}

Once that's done, you can post your config (you will need to remove the `-s` that hides the curl output). Once posted, you will want to be checking the logs of the running Connect process, or you can also go to `http://localhost:8083/connectors/RedisSinkConnector1/status`

Given what you've shown, and you got this far, both of the above probably say something about a Connection Exception to localhost:6379, since that's the default connection. You'll have to provide `"redis.hosts": "redis:6379"` as a property.

Then, also mentioned in the documentation

> This connector expects records from Kafka to have a key and value that are stored as bytes or a string

So, it wouldn't hurt to also add key & value converter to your properties as well to specify the data types. If you are directly using the Connect container from Confluent, it's probably set to use the Avro converter, not string or bytes one

Here's an example of a valid configuration that you can POST

```
{
  "name" : "RedisSinkConnector1",
  "config" : {
    "connector.class" : "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max" : "1",
    "topics" : "mostafa",
    "redis.hosts": "redis:6379",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
  }
}
```

With those adjustments, I would think sending any simple key-value message would work and then use redis-cli to run some scan/get key query

Comment: Would you please tell where to add `redis.hosts`? I don't know what the property really is.

Comment: In the json you posted. It's described in the README

Comment: Thanks, I try it in 2 hours. but I will give upvote for your descriptive answer. <3

Comment: After adding the redis.host to connect.json file and then running the `curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data @connector.json http://localhost:8083/connectors`, it still doesn't work properly. It even doesn't create a new topic in kafka. I have created a new topic in kafka container manually and then nothing was written in redis!

Comment: Should I map the connect.json file to the kafka container and then curl to the following address?
curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data @connector.json http://localhost:8083/connectors

Comment: Connect Sinks don't create topics, only read. And you'd probably want data in the topic before starting the connector anyway since it defaults to reading from the end of the topic. Meaning if you had data in the topic, then start the connector, you'd still see nothing... and it doesn't matter where the JSON file is located as long as the URL is correct

Comment: Sorry I didn't get. I have created a new topic. I have produced some data in that topic. and then run the `curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data @connector.json http://localhost:8083/connectors` command. I didn't see anything in redis db using `redis-cli keys '*' `

Comment: And there are still no errors in the logs and the /status endpoint says its `RUNNING`?

Comment: Neither `http://localhost:8083/connectors/RedisSinkConnector1/status` nor `curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data @connector.json http://localhost:8083/connectors` prints nothing.

Comment: When you POST to `/connectors`, it requires both `name` and `config` at the top-level. The output should be the whole response. I don't know why you get nothing. https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html#post--connectors

Comment: Oh, you get nothing because you have `curl -s`... Remove the silence flag.`-s`... So you are probably getting an error in the POST, and the status endpoint is a 404 because connector doesn't exist

Comment: Yeah, You are right. I have get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8083: Connection refused`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your Connect Server needs to be running

Comment: How can I run the connect server? sorry to ask so many questions. I am very new to these structure

Comment: Well... I don't know how you are testing anything... You have a docker compose file, right? Try `docker-compose up`? Or are you just doing `docker run`?

Comment: That repo you linked to doesn't have a Kafka Connect container in it, by the way

Comment: I'm using docker-compose up. then I try docker exec -it kafka bash.  `cd opt/kafka/` and here I create a new topic and produce some data. finally in my local computer I run the `curl ...`

Comment: But they claimed that it does making the connection.

Comment: It will, if you 1) Actually run a Kafka Connect server 2) Build and install the Redis connector source code into that server... Seems like you skipped a lot of steps. We've used that connector at my job, with some changes, so I know it does work

Comment: I have connected so many databases to kafka and spark. But this one is very complicated and I really don't have any idea how to implement. Is it possible for you to create a repository?

Comment: I don't have a repo that uses Redis... Either you can learn how to [install the connector within a Docker container](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#connect-installing-plugins) Or you could use a different connector altogether that is already mostly configured. https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/sink/redis.html#lenses-quickstart

Comment: I have downloaded the jar file and copied to the `opt/kafka/kafka-connect-redis-1.2.2-2.1.0-all.jar`.  What else I have to do?

Comment: You would need to find `connect-distributed.sh` script along with its property file, edit the property file, then run the script with it

Comment: Or you could just add another container that runs Kafka Connect (like your datagen container, or Debezium, or the one from Mongo). Each one of those is able to use the same Redis connector JAR and your connector config

Comment: Hi Jordan, I have tried the way you said but I couldn't create a proper connection. I would be thankful to guide me with a repository. 
Thanks for you support. <3